# How to prove that $\mathscr{H}$ is dense in $C_0$

Tags: approximation, approximation-theory, function-spaces

Let us define $C_0$ as the space of all $f \in C^0(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ such that $\lim_{\|x\| \to +\infty} \|f(x)\|=0$.

Let be $\sigma>0$ fixed and define $\mathscr{H}$ the vector space generated by all function, for $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$:
$$g_v(u)=\frac{1}{(2\pi \sigma^2)^{\frac n 2}}e^{-\frac{\|u-v\|^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$ for all $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

How can I prove that $\mathscr{H}$ is dense in $C_0$?

I know that is related with the Stone-Weiestrass theorem but I don't know how.

Comment: Isn't it exactly a consequence of the locally compact version of Stone-Weierstrass? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Comment: @Raoul To literally apply the usual formulation of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, you'd need to know that the allegedly dense space is a subalgebra of $C_0$, i.e., that it's closed under pointwise multiplication.

Comment: Right, thanks. When we multiply two such functions, we get something of the same form, but with $\sigma^2$ replaced by $\sigma^2/2$, which is not in the space. It is probably in the closure though.

Comment: What about the first answer to this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1761322/why-this-set-is-dense-in-c-0-mathbbr/1773738

Comment: @jacopoburelli Thank you very much, that is very interesting, but actually I do not know the "Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem". Further more that proof needs the Hahn-Banach theorem and I am asking myself if there is a way to avoid it.